# RDMA setup in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rdma

I'm quite beginner with AWS, and I need to set up RDMA connectivity between client and server. Can anybody give me any idea, hint, guide or anything that helps me ?

Thank you

Comment: Amazon EC2 virtual machines are just like "normal" computers. So, do whatever you would do on a normal computer and it will probably work! Hint: Check your Security Groups to ensure that they permit the necessary inbound access between instances. Let us know if you run into any particular problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you. 
I have been trying to spin up an i3.large instance because I need NVMe. Unfortunately, I encounter a Failure in "initiating launches". 

The error says: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: When does it say that? Is it when you try to launch the Amazon EC2 instances? If so, then you should talk to whoever controls your AWS accounts because they might need to assign you more permissions. Can you launch any other instance sizes (eg t3.medium)? That information might help them update your permissions.

Comment: There are a couple of tutorials on Amazon's [Elastic Fabric Adapter page](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/efa/).

Answer (score 0):

As of 02/2023, the only type of AWS instance that supports RDMA that I can find is [P4d](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p4/?nc1=h_ls). And if you decide to go with that AWS may be able to help you with further instructions.

But, SoftRoCE will work on any type of instance. SoftRoCE is a software stack providing RDMA connections without any hardware requirement. The CentOS7 machine I am using has the rdma_core code already in it's kernel so I can start it by following [this blog](https://iwmj.wordpress.com/2018/09/03/how-to-build-the-development-environment-of-software-rdma-over-converged-ethernet-roce/comment-page-1/?unapproved=962&moderation-hash=54bbe980036b25ffdbfeae8ffb1e0dc6#comment-962).